# Problem with the AzerothCore DB auto installation under windows 10

Tags: azerothcore

Hello I got a problem while trying to launch the db_assembler with functions.sh, I'm under windows 10 with MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to go in conf/config.sh and change the ligne with DB_MYSQL_EXEC="" and put my the path of my mysql.exe (c:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/mysql.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Add Mysql Bin folder to your environment Variables in Windows, helped for me and works now very well! If you need help with it just Ask ;)